# Newman error: unknown option `--folder FOLDER_NAME'

Tags: postman, newman

I have a problem with folder running in Newman. I run the following :

```
$ newman run collection_name.json --folder "FOLDER_NAME" -e environment_name.json
```

And it returns :

```
error: unknown option `--folder FOLDER_NAME'
```

I tried to write the FOLDER_NAME into brackets, with and without quotes but I have always this error message.

Comment: Which version of Newman do you have? What's the folder name? It would only need quotes around it if it have spaces. I just run it locally at that option is working for me. Version 4.4.0 on a Mac.

Comment: I have the 4.4.0 Newman version, my folder name doesn't have any spaces but have underscores.